# removing handler callbacks stops working when leaving and returning to Activity

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I have a handler and a runnable, the runnable posts a toast to the screen every 5 seconds, here is the code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DISPLAY MESSAGE" + walking, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
    }
};
```

Within the same activity I can remove the callback by pressing the kill button, calling this:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

When the above is called the Toast stops displaying so all is good so far. When I leave my activity to go to another activity, the toast messages keep displaying, this is what I want, but when I go back to the first activity where the runnable was created and press the kill button, it does not remove the runnable. I can no longer remove the runnable when leaving and coming back.

I have tried using almost all of the examples I have seen using Handlers and runnables on SO and nothing has helped me figure this out.

Could it be when I leave my Activity and return it creates new runnable and handler objects? If so why does the initial runnable continue to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a service that runs in background,
then kill the service when the button is pressed. That's the easiest way you can implement this.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this, I researched it when I read your answer but I am unsure of exactly what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is poor form to keep long-standing references in an activity. They will easily and often get destroyed and recreated, even when you rotate the phone! What's happening is when the Activity gets recreated, there is a new Runnable and Handler object created as you suspect.

To get around this without resorting to services, what I do is create a Fragment… let's call it StateFragment.

Give this Fragment no view, so it is invisible to the user. It is only used to store variables. When your activity is created, add it to the activity if it is not already present. Finally, in the Fragment class itself, in its onCreate, setRetainInstance to true.

I will admit this is a bit of a hack but it is a very convenient way to preserve variables in a process when activities are created and destroyed. In this case when the Activity gets destroyed and recreated, the fragment is likely retained unless it has been in the background for some time and cleaned up by the GC. Some code below:

```
public class StateFragment extends Fragment{
  //add some variables here
  //these will not last long time!
  Handler handler;
  Runnable runnable;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
    setRetainInstance(true); //<--this is the important part!
        Handler = new Handler... etc.



  }
}
```

Now in your Activity, have a class-level variable to keep a reference:

```
public Class MainActivity  extends FragmentActivity {
StateFragment sf;
```

Then in your "onCreate" you need to check if it exists, and attach it otherwise:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
sf=(StateFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("storage");
if (sf==null)
{
  sf=new StateFragment();
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(sf, "storage").commit();
}
```

In general, I find that the volatility of Activities is a huge pain and having some more persistent storage is generally a great boon. Now you can easily reference the Runnable as

```
sf.runnable
```

Comment: I've seen this method of storing state used before, I think by the Glide framework IIRC.  In my case it was really annoying since it messed with my fragment stack and I needed complete control of it.  With this in mind I'd think twice before going with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following it uses a timer class for every displaying your `Toast` every 5 seconds
start the backhelper service class from your class:

```
public class BackHelper extends Service {   
        @Override
        public void onCreate() 
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
            super.onCreate();
                        Timer timer = new Timer();
                TimerTask updateProfile = new BackHelper(sock.this);
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateProfile, 0, 5000);      
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
            super.onDestroy();
        }
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "Service onstart");

            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
            return null;
        }
    public class sock extends TimerTask
        {
        @Override
            public void run()
            {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "DISPLAY MESSAGE" + walking, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
            }
```

Comment: @deucalioan0 try this if problem exists reply me with your logcat